# Como faço appends nos models do Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Tenho um model no Mongoose que faz referencia a outro model, e preciso trazer os dados desse outro model no meu controller, segue código:

**Model Empresa.js:**

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    nome: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    thumbnail_id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Empresa', schema);
```

Note que tenho o campo thumbnail_id nesse model e preciso retornar os dados da thubmnail no controller, segue o segundo model que tenho que retornar:

**Model Thubmnail.js:**

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    usuario: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    thumbnail: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Media', schema);
```

**Segue retorno atual:**

```
{
    "_id": "5d9e4623c745c70d2c05e418",
    "nome": "Teste",
    "thumbnail_id": 1,
    "__v": 0
}
```

**Segue retorno esperado:**

```
{
    "_id": "5d9e4623c745c70d2c05e418",
    "nome": "Teste2",
    "thumbnail_id": 1,
    "media": {
        "usuario": "Teste",
        "thumbnail": "uploads/thumb.jpg",
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Segue link interessante de relacionamentos, incluindo UmParaMuitos:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245685/mongoose-one-to-many/35245953

Answer (score 3, accepted):

o ideal seria você referenciar da seguinte forma no seu Model.

Exemplo:

```
user: {
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, //aqui é a referencia ao id 
   ref: 'User' //Nome da "tabela"
},
```

Acho que no seu caso ficaria assim no seu Empresa.js:

```
thumbnail: {
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, //aqui é a referencia ao id 
   ref: 'Thumbnail' //Nome da "tabela"
},
```